# Read password from stdin

Tags: python, passwords, prompt, interactive

Scenario: An interactive CLI Python program, that is in need for a password. That means also, there's no GUI solution possible.

In bash I could get a password read in without re-prompting it on screen via

```
read -s
```

Is there something similar for Python? I.e.,

```
password = raw_input('Password: ', dont_print_statement_back_to_screen)
```

Alternative: Replace the typed characters with '*' before sending them back to screen (aka browser' style).

Answer (score 298, accepted):

```
>>> import getpass
>>> pw = getpass.getpass()
```

Comment: Yeah, them batteries. ;-) One of the cool thing with Python is its ability to bind easily with binaries in other language, in particular C, hence leveraging a lot of existing stuff (such as getpass(), I believe)

Comment: Even better, getpass() deals with the situation in which a CLI tool is being fed data via STDIN and yet you want the ability to type the password yourself. Great tool!

Comment: @Tiemen but I came here looking for a solution to do this because getpass() is still prompting me and waiting for a password even though I piped the password to my script

Comment: For me, getpass poppoed up a window (not what I wanted, nor what its help said) and didn't obscure the password when I typed it in! Code to reproduce: import getpass; getpass.getpass()

Comment: @Tiemen IIRC, unix tools support that by re-opening the stderr stream for reading, instead of for writing. It's a neat hack, yeah?

Comment: but this doesn't display '*' as one types. How does one achieve this?

Comment: @Jason you don't want that

Answer (score 56):

Yes, [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html): "Prompt the user for a password without echoing."

**Edit:** I had not played with this module myself yet, so this is what I just cooked up (wouldn't be surprised if you find similar code all over the place, though):

```
import getpass

def login():
    user = input("Username [%s]: " % getpass.getuser())
    if not user:
        user = getpass.getuser()

    pprompt = lambda: (getpass.getpass(), getpass.getpass('Retype password: '))

    p1, p2 = pprompt()
    while p1 != p2:
        print('Passwords do not match. Try again')
        p1, p2 = pprompt()

    return user, p1
```

(This is Python 3.x; use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) when using Python 2.x.)