# How to take user input as asterisk in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently I am using Python 2.7.4

How do I take an `input` or `raw_input` from the user in a **hidden** manner *(Such as using asterisk)* ?
---without showing others what is being input just like **password**.

Comment: Check out the standard [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/getpass.html) module.

Comment: check this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631629/masking-user-input-in-python-with-asterisks