# how do i make a password in my python program to be shown as asterisk

Tags: python

```
def logInOkay():
  print("You must login before proceeding")
  userId = input("User ID")
  userPw = input("Password")
  if (userId=="Mr Leeman") and (userPw=="Treeroad!"):
    return True
  else:
    print("Error in userId or password")
    return False
```

I need to be able to enter (treeroad!), but it need to be hidden and replaced with asterisk.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805078/how-do-i-convert-a-password-into-asterisks-while-it-is-being-entered/35805111

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use getch() instead of input().

Refer to the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631629/masking-user-input-in-python-with-asterisks) post.