# How to make the output of input function look like a * symbol?

Tags: python

I'm making a program where the user needs to enter a password. I'm using the input function for this. How would I make it so that the user sees *** symbols instead of the actual letters for their password?

[image: image of code]

Comment: Hi there, take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631629/masking-user-input-in-python-with-asterisks) question. It may help.

Comment: You using a gui or what? This thing called mask.Plz be more explicit

Comment: BTW, you generally should not define functions inside other functions, unless you have a good reason to do that.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getpass module to hide the password entered on the console.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/getpass.html

Comment: Sure, but `getpass` isn't _guaranteed_ to hide the password: "If echo free input is unavailable `getpass()` falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from `sys.stdin` and issuing a `GetPassWarning`."

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function like below

```
import getpass 
pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
```