# How to mask a password in a login system in python3

Tags: python

i am creating this basic login system and i want to replace the characters of the password as the user enters them and not display the password as the user enters it instead display the # symbol

```
def login() :
    l_user = input('Username: ')
    l_pass= input("password")
    with open('username.txt', mode='r')as user_file:
            validate_u = user_file.readlines()
    with open('password.txt', mode='r')as pass_file:
        validate_p = pass_file.readlines()
    if l_user + "\n" in validate_u:  # ReadLines() adds newlines
        user_num = validate_u.index(l_user + "\n")
        if l_pass + "\n" == validate_p[user_num]:
            print("Password correct!")
        else:
            print("Password incorrect!")
    else:
        print("Cannot find your username!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Masking user input in python with asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631629/masking-user-input-in-python-with-asterisks)

Comment: no it doesn't because in python 3 input is used instead of raw input

Comment: Check this out then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54603772/5362583

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
>>> from getpass import getpass
>>> p = getpass(prompt='Enter your password:')
Enter your password:
>>> p
'pswrd'
```

Comment: but i want to mask the password like as user times it it prints '*' on screen instead of typed password