# How to protect password in python

Tags: python-2.7

How should I protect my password in Python 2.7? `getpass.getpass()` method is not working. At the time when I run my code, the password is visible.

I have done something like this:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

try:
     emailid=input("what is your email id: ")    
     password=getpass.getpass("enter your password: ")
     M.login(emailid,password)
```

Comment: Doing a quick web search, the getpass() method you've already referenced is the only one anyone is referring to. Here is an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761744/python-read-password-from-stdin. Perhaps you could post your non working getpass() usage.

Comment: passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
this is what i m getting

Comment: [edit] your post to show the code for trying to use getpass

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal" when running from IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878741/getpasswarning-can-not-control-echo-on-the-terminal-when-running-from-idle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got it.  i used the method getpass.getpass(prompt='password=')

second thing is that this will only on run command prompt of a system(no third party application will give output for getpass.getpass())