# "GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal" when running from IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code:

```
import getpass

p = getpass.getpass(prompt='digite a senha\n')
if p == '12345':
    print('YO Paul')
else:
    print('BRHHH')
print('O seu input foi:', p) # p = seu input
```

I got this warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/getpass.py", line 63
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal. Warning: Password input may be echoed.
```

Comment: That would be system and terminal-dependent: https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html Prompt the user for a password without echoing. ... If echo free input is unavailable getpass() falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from sys.stdin and issuing a GetPassWarning.

Comment: I think the warning is telling you precisely that there is *not* a way (that Python knows or recognizes) to prevent the password from being echoed on the system where the message is emitted.

Comment: I am using IDLE: Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux

Comment: `getpass` working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616813/can-i-get-console-input-without-echo-in-python

Comment: Note

If you call getpass from within IDLE, the input may be done in the terminal you launched IDLE from rather than the idle window itself.

Comment: IDLE interferes with normal console input & output; `getpass` was not designed to be used in such environments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use an actual terminal -- that is, an environment where `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are connected to `/dev/tty`, or another PTY-compliant device.

The IDLE REPL does not meet this requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Run your code in terminal, instead of the IDE. you will see that there is no more warning there. 
To run your code, enter this command in terminal:

```
python3 your_program.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than deal with changing the current working directory in a terminal that has not started Python (which would mean you type something like `python3 script.py`--and it will fail unless the current working directory is already specified), start Python in your terminal and run this one-line command:

`exec(open('C:\folder\script.py').read())`

where you change the path string `'C:\folder\script.py'` to match wherever your file is located on disk (the string *does* need to be specified with quotes).

Comment: This will get rid of the warning.  That being said, it also does not provide *any* feedback on how many characters you have entered, how many backspaces you have pressed, etc. so if your password is long then:
```getpass.getpass(prompt='Securely enter your password (minimum of xx characters):  ')``` is about as good as you are going to get using that package.

Answer (score 1):

use cmd ie. command prompt and then run the file in it.

like:

```
python abc.py
```