# How To Show Text While Inputting As Dots In Python Terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, terminal, passwords

Is there Any way to convert Text to Dots while Inputting In python 3 Terminal.
my Code is:

```
[........
user = input('Enter Your UserName:')
pass = input('Enter Your Password:')
........]
```

I know the Module [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html).But it don't work in Terminal , It gives warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
```

If it can work without warning and hide text,Please tell me.
Is there any Otherway somthing like:

```
import sys
shell = sys.stdout.shell
shell.show input as '0';
....
```

I am creating a script that asks the user to give Password but it looks bad if Password is being showed while typing.
I am here with a hope that you may help me.
If you want more information,I am ready to provide to you.
Thanks....

Comment: What terminal and OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal" when running from IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878741/getpasswarning-can-not-control-echo-on-the-terminal-when-running-from-idle)

Comment: I am on windows.Check this [Image](https://postimg.org/image/f86ngmmez/f97b4fac/).

Comment: Any other way Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using password input with tkinter separately is a bad idea.
I created this one in which it has username and password except password only:

```
from tkinter import * #(tkinter (A cross-platform GUI)

top = Tk()
def callback(): #what to do after button(Submit) pressed
    print(E2.get()) #printing first input
    print(E1.get()) #printing second input
    top.destroy() #exiting tkinter
top.title('Login')
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.grid(row=0, column=0) #setting up position for user name field
E2 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E2.grid(row=0, column=1)

L1 = Label(top, text="Password")  # text for second name,currently Password
L1.grid(row=1, column=0) #setting up position for password field
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5,show='*') #hidding the text with *
E1.grid(row=1, column=1)
MyButton1 = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback) # button named submit
# 'command=callback ' the command you want to do|we have created a function callback

MyButton1.grid(row=3, column=1) # position for button

top.mainloop()
```

Hope It will be helpful for you.
**Getpass** is not for **IDLE**

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `getpass` inside [Python IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879520/446792).

Also trying things like redirecting *stdout* causes shell restart inside *IDLE*:

```
import sys
import os
import getpass

sys.stdout = os.devnull
getpass.getpass()

== RESTART: Shell ==
```

Maybe you can use `tkinter` dialog window to prompt user for password:

```
# import tkinter (a crossplatform GUI)
import tkinter

# import a simple dialog form with a label and a button
# so you don't have to build one yourself
import tkinter.simpledialog

# create an empty main window for GUI,
# without it you will get an error:
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'winfo_viewable'
tk_root = tkinter.Tk()

# you don't really need to show it, so hide it immediately
tk_root.withdraw()

# create a dialog window with title 'Password'
# and a text label 'Enter Your Password:'
# also hide typed password with *
passwd = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('Password','Enter Your Password:', show='*')
```

Just save it as a function:

```
def get_pass():
    import tkinter
    import tkinter.simpledialog
    tk_root = tkinter.Tk()
    tk_root.withdraw()
    return tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('Password','Enter Your Password:', show='*')
```

and use `get_pass()` instead of `getpass()`.

Comment: @mini  I've updated code to work with Python 3.5 & 3.6.

Comment: Its perfect but can you convert all the code to one unreadable small line?

Comment: @mini I've added some comments to that snippet. What do you mean by "convert all the code to one unreadable small line"?

Comment: We can Also Make It Into A module.Write The Function **get_pass()** in **pypass.py** .Now Place It In _Lib_ folder in _python36-32_ .Now You       can use It Like:   `import pypass` `pypass.get_pass()`and it will work.Also In 1 line.