# Python - How to Hide user input

Tags: python

So I'm developing a Python code for a school project, basic guess the number code, and when people enter a number I need the other people not to be able to see it on screen. This is the code I'm working with at the moment

```
l=1
import random
import random
a = random.randint(1,50)
b = random.randint(1,50)
while l:
   user_1 = str(input("Welcome player 1, please enter your name --> "))
   user_2 = str(input("Welcome player 2, please enter your name --> "))

   guess1 = int(input("(PLAYER1) Enter a number --> ")


   if a == guess1:
         print ("You guessed it!")
         break
   elif a > guess1:
         print ("Too low!")
   elif guess1 > 50:
         print ("Out of bounds, number must be between 1 and 50!")
   else:
      print ("Too high!")
```

I need it so that when I enter the number, it either shows an * or just doesn't show anything. I have tried a ***getpass.getpass*** module but it returns this error/warning:
Warning (from warnings module):

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\getpass.py", line 101
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password:
```

On top of that error, it doesn't work (blur the text). I'm using python 3.4.0 and I'm unable to change that, any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I notice this was marked as duplicate, only my version of python doesn't accept raw_inputs, as used in the duplicate text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38878741/6445069

Comment: so there's no way to do this without using a terminal?

Comment: Keystroke echoing is controlled by the terminal you use, so If the one you're using (idle, etc) does not work (ie, it doesn't respect the request to not show keystroke inputs), you need a different terminal.

Comment: Maybe you can consider making a small interface.