# GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal

Tags: python, hash

I am creating a dice game and want to introduce password hashing and user is required to enter their username and password. I am new to hashing and I tried this:

```
from getpass import getpass
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac as pwhash

def login(users):
    username = input('please enter username: ')
    if username not in users:
        print("access denied")
        exit()

    password_hash = None
    while password_hash != users[username]:
        password_hash = pwhash("sha256", getpass().encode("ascii"), b"t4h20p8g24j", 100000)

    print("access granted")
    return username
login(users)
```

I then received the following message on console:

```
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
```

so I tried a different ide (went from idle to intellij pycharm)
yet the same issue still came about.

I saw other questions but 
`an environment where stdin, stdout and stderr are connected to /dev/tty, or another PTY-compliant device.`
doesn't really make sense to me I tried to comment but I need more rep.
Also I'm running on PyCharm not idle

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal" when running from IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878741/getpasswarning-can-not-control-echo-on-the-terminal-when-running-from-idle)

Comment: I tried to comment on that for a bit more clarification but it says I need more reputation

Comment: Then you should refer to that question in yours, and explain how exactly it doesn't answer your problem. Also, try to create a [mcve] when asking questions: the whole hashing/users part in your current question is irrelevant if your question is only about using `getpass`.

Comment: In short: don't try to use your script from PyCharm, but use a real terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input was echoed because the while loop never exited as the condition was not met:
the password in the dictionary was stored as plain text
just needed to hash the values in the dictionary.

```
def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
    password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
    return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()
```