# How to hide user input for passwords

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program which includes a login function. Ideally I want to hide the password input. I've done some searching and found the `getpass` module yet can't seem to get it work.

```
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass("Please enter your password: ")
```

That's what I've got so far and every time it just throws up this error message:

```
   return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Please enter your password:
```

It's probably me being really stupid but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong

Comment: Similar [warning/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878741/getpasswarning-can-not-control-echo-on-the-terminal-when-running-from-idle)