# Python modifying sys.stdin and sys.stdout

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent sys.stdin from being displayed to sys.stdout. I'm guessing the correct terminology would be to flush sys.stdin at a carriage return? I would still like sys.stdin to be seen before the carriage return is entered.

Normal behavior:

```
>>>print("test")
test
```

Desired behavior:

```
>>>
test
```

Comment: Let me know if the linked page doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thats not the solution I was looking for. I would like sys.stdin to be viewable while its being typed and only flushed on carriage return.

Comment: @user1023102: You'll want to have full control of the terminal in that case; use `curses` to do so.

Comment: maybe thats what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/1761754/1722117